# Difference between findOne and findById in mongo

Tags: mongodb

Still trying to get up to speed with Mongo.

I have a method that is intended to duplicate a document in a mongo collection. However it needs to also duplicate another record in another collection associated with the primary document. If I forget about the association and fetch the document with `findById` like so:

```
const docToDuplicate = await this.findById(id);
```

I can do what I need to to `docToDuplicate` and save it as a new record, but if I take the association into account and fetch it like so:

```
const docToDuplicate = this.docModel
      .findOne({ _id: id })
      .populate('association')
      .exec();
```

and try to make changes `docToDuplicate` it will mutate the original document rather create a new one.

Is there a way I can take what is returned with `findOne` and not mutate the original document?